# Magento 2 : How to add sorting option to review?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sorting, review

I need to add sorting option (By New, By Old, By Highest Rating, By Lowest Rating) to review section in Magento 2.1 Product Detail View.

So that the customer can sort ratings using the drop down.By default, this does not provide Sorting drop-down except the pagination.Has someone done this in Magento 2.1?

Please help..